# Let x and y be nonzero vectors in Rn, show this:

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

[image]

I do not understand how to start this problem since the x and y on the right are not bolded as vectors. Does this matter?

Comment: All three $x$'s in the question are actually different.... But probably they are just the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, the x and y in the question are supposed to be bolded as well.

Comment: they need to be bolded as vectors , otherwise you can't prove anything.

Comment: Okay, I will assume they are vectors then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Considering the context, it is highly likely that $x$ and $y$ are the same arbitrary but fixed nonzero vectors on both sides of the inequality.